# Reliable way of giving away goldfish

Tags: goldfish, pond, reproduction

About a year ago i built a small pond with 5 goldfish inside.

Apparently they really liked it because they started reproducing a lot and now there are more than 15 and i'm guessing that the space they have is starting to get a bit cramped. I'm also positive that they will not stop coming anytime soon.

Is there a good and reliable way to give them away (for free). I tried online but so far only one person got 2 fishes.

Should i try pet stores? Also IIRC releasing them into the wild is not a good idea and can get you big fines.

If it's helpful i live in italy.

Comment: Please see this [related question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/26106/12501). The fines are there to protect fragile ecosystems against those cute little goldfish that grow into malicious feeding monsters.

Comment: Yeah, knew about that. That's why i thought it wasn't a good idea. I once went fishing in a lake and caught a goldfish that was twice the size of any other fishes