# Should I euthanize my fish?

Tags: fish, diseases, euthanasia, cichlid

For almost a year, my pet cichlid has been favoring laying on his right side at the bottom of the tank, but still swims around (clumsily) and eats. I do monthly water changes, I've used Pimafix and Melafix, I've tried feeding him boiled, peeled peas. What worries me further is that now his right eye has turned cloudy and pooling with blood. I'm very worried and torn on what I should do at this point, especially since he is still eating... anyone has experience with this?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any experience with fish, but should you decide to euthanize your fish, please see this related question: [What's the least painful way to euthanize a fish?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/1765/12501).

Comment: You should contact your vet to see what is happenning to your fish.